# Continuous subset and ranking using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I have a dataset like below:
[image]

Now, I need the `output` as below:

```
start_time  end_time    count
10:01   10:04   3
10:05   10:07   2
```

For this purpose, I wrote a query but it is not giving me the desired sequence. My query is as below:

```
with on_off as 
(
select  time,status,case when status!=lag(status) over(order by time) then 1 else 0 end as continuous_count
  from time_status
)
,
grp as 
(
  select *, row_number() over(partition by continuous_count order by time) rnk from  on_off
)
select * from grp order by time
```

It generates the output as below:
[image]

But in the `rank` section I need something as below:
[image]

So, what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Here are the `PostgresSQL` DDLs:

```
create table time_status(time varchar(10)  null, status varchar(10) null);

INSERT into  time_status(time,status) values('10:01','ON');
INSERT into  time_status(time,status) values('10:02','ON');
INSERT into  time_status(time,status) values('10:03','ON');
INSERT into  time_status(time,status) values('10:04','OFF');
INSERT into  time_status(time,status) values('10:05','ON');
INSERT into  time_status(time,status) values('10:06','ON');
INSERT into  time_status(time,status) values('10:07','OFF');
```

Comment: MySQL is not PostgreSQL. Please do not tag spam. Choose only tags that are actually applicable to your question. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and misusing them is a quick way to get your question closed or downvoted.

Comment: I don't know how to exactly do it, but you would need to use a loop to iterate through the table and print the first ON, then the next OFF, change back to ON to print and so on. In my experience it was always easier to do this kind of work in a different programming language than SQL. Whatever you are most comfortable with and can work with SQL should do the trick. For example Python can do this easy, there I could even give you an example code.

Comment: It's a typical [gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands+postgresql) problem, and the provided answer is pretty good to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT min(time) as start_time,
       max(time) as end_time,
       sum(case when status = 'ON' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
  FROM (SELECT time, status,
               sum(case when status = 'OFF' then 1 else 0 end)
                 over (order by time desc) as grp
          FROM time_status) _
 GROUP BY grp
 ORDER BY min(time);
```

->[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jdh9SWFkcwBKjZ8Rp2sZpY/0)

Comment: Yeah, this worked. However, how can I check for continuity in SQL?

Comment: What do you mean by "checking for continuity"?

Comment: like continuous subset and new subset

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what you need. If that's related to rnk column in your question, once you have the groups from the subquery in my answer you can easily rank within these groups. Otherwise I suggest that like you did for this question, please post another with example dataset and expected output.